# $I_T:= \{f(x) \in F[x] : f(T) v \in W\}$ is an ideal in $F[x]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ideals

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$ and $W$ be a proper $T$-invariant subspace of $V$. I want to prove

> For any $v \in V$, show that $I_T:= \{f(x) \in F[x] : f(T) v \in W\}$ is an ideal in $F[x]$.

---

Recall the definition of an ideal : Let $I\subset R$ is an ideal, if (1) $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$ and (2) for every $r\in R$ and every $x\in I$, the product $rx \in I$, $xr\in I$.

The followings are my trial :

$(I_T,+)$ is a subgroup of $F[t]$. Let $f_1, f_2 \in I_T$, then $f_1(T)v, f_2(T)v \in W$. and so linear combination of them is again $W$.

Let $g\in F[t], h \in I_T$. WTS $ gh \in I_T$.

Let $g = \sum_i a_i t^i$ and $h \in \sum_j b_j t^j$ with $h(T)v \in W$.  Then it is enough to show $T h(T) v \in W$. i.e., Since $h(T)v \in W$, $T(h(T(v))\in W$ since $W$ is $T-$invariant. i.e., $T(W) \subset W$.

---

Is my approach correct? Is there any other way to show $I_T$ is an ideal of $F[t]$?

Comment: Another way to see that this is an ideal is the following: $V$ has a structure of $R=F[x]$-module, and $W$ is a submodule of $V$. Then $I_T$ is nothing but the annihilator of $\hat v\in V/W$ in $R$.